# I facing Braintree Credential Validation issues

Tags: magento2.4.2

I have integrated Braintree with my setup its working means all transactions done
but when I click Validate credentials buttons show errors like

"Braintree Credential Validation Failed
Your Braintree account credentials could not be validated. Please ensure you have selected the correct environment and entered a valid Merchant ID, Public Key, and Private Key"

but all my Merchant ID, Public Key, and Private Key are correct, but why show these errors. Please help me. [image]please also check below image

Comment: may be you are using live credential in sandbox environment.

Comment: no use sandbox details

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was because I put the wrong Merchant Account ID under Advanced Settings. I assumed that Merchant ID was equivalent to Merchant Account ID, but no, they're two different things.

You can get your Merchant ID on the dashboard of the Braintree sandbox.

You can get your Merchant Account ID through Account -> Merchant Account Info -> Merchant Account ID. If you only have one merchant account, you can leave the value blank in the configuration.

Besides the advanced setting for the account was that of production not of the sandbox, remove this to use default or add the one from the sandbox account.